# How do you control the location of header files in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I'm installing a package that was built with CMake.  It installs header files in a nonstandard location.  Is there a variable I can use at installation time to change that path?

The current CMake invocation is:

```
cmake /p/a/t/h -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib
```

I'm looking for `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCDIR` or `-DCMAKE_INCLUDE_DIR` or `-DCMAKE_INCLUDE_HEADERDIR`, or something.
(For example, I'm trying to accomplish what would be done with `configure --includedir=/usr/include` using an autoconf generated configure script.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, CMake packages needn't to allow user to modify installation paths on *per-component basis*.

But if the package includes CMake module [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) and uses variables from it for install components, user may affect on components' installation paths by setting some of these variables. Each such variable has a form

```
CMAKE_INSTALL_<dir>
```

where `<dir>` may be on of (according to the documentation):

```
BINDIR           - user executables (bin)
SBINDIR          - system admin executables (sbin)
LIBEXECDIR       - program executables (libexec)
SYSCONFDIR       - read-only single-machine data (etc)
SHAREDSTATEDIR   - modifiable architecture-independent data (com)
LOCALSTATEDIR    - modifiable single-machine data (var)
LIBDIR           - object code libraries (lib or lib64 or lib/<multiarch-tuple> on Debian)
INCLUDEDIR       - C header files (include)
OLDINCLUDEDIR    - C header files for non-gcc (/usr/include)
DATAROOTDIR      - read-only architecture-independent data root (share)
DATADIR          - read-only architecture-independent data (DATAROOTDIR)
INFODIR          - info documentation (DATAROOTDIR/info)
LOCALEDIR        - locale-dependent data (DATAROOTDIR/locale)
MANDIR           - man documentation (DATAROOTDIR/man)
DOCDIR           - documentation root (DATAROOTDIR/doc/PROJECT_NAME)
```

---

Note, that the package needn't to use all of these variables. E.g., the package may use variable *CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR* for install libraries, but ignore *CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR* when install headers.