# How to specify ./configure's parameters '--includedir' and '--libdir' to cmake

Tags: makefile, cmake, installation, configure, log4cplus

Question about installing `log4cplus`.

log4cplus has two way to make & install.

1. `./configure && make && make install`
2. `cmake xxx && make && make install`

When I use the 1st one, parameters `--includedir=PATH` and `--libdir=PATH` can be specified to `configure`, because I want to install them into different paths.

How can I specify the two equivalent parameters to `cmake`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since package *log4cplus* uses CMake module [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/GNUInstallDirs.html), you may use variables *CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR* and *CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR* for adjust installation paths for libraries and headers correspondingly:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=<libdir-path> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=<includedir-path>
```

For more info see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41024820/how-do-you-control-the-location-of-header-files-in-cmake).